# Babel not transpiling imported node_modules to ES5 - includes ES2015 syntax

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

My babel+webpack config works fine, but the resulting bundle isn't runnable in IE11 as it contains `const` declarations. I thought having the `es2015` preset was enough to fix this? Running `$(npm bin)/babel test/some-es2015.js` produces strict ES5.1 code, so Babel seems to work, but the actual code that borks in IE11 is in modules imported from `node_modules`.

When grepping for `'const '` in my resulting bundle I get certain lines like this (the eval is due to eval source mapping btw):

```
eval("\nObject.defineProperty(exports, \"__esModule\", { value: true });\nconst validator = __webpack_require__(/*! validator */ \"./node_modules/tcomb-additional-types/node_modules/validator/index.js\");\nconst t = __webpack_require__(/*! tcomb */ \"./node_modules/tcomb/index.js\");\nconst IP = t.refinement(t.String, validator.isIP);\nexports.IP = IP;\nexports.default = IP;\n//# sourceMappingURL=ip.js.map\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./node_modules/tcomb-additional-types/lib/string/ip.js?");
```

The important part to note is the stuff such as `const validator =`. This isn't ES5.1 syntax. My own code seems to have been transpiled to ES5 just fine. I can see this file in `/node_modules/tcomb-additional-types/lib/string/ip.js`, where they use `const`, so this isn't Babel adding `const`s, but the source containing them. Most of the other packages are ES5.

So far, I have found that most `const`s are from `material-ui` and `tcomb-additional-types`.

**Babel .babelrc:**

```
{
    "compact": false,
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "es2017"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["transform-runtime", {
            "polyfill": false,
            "regenerator": true
        }],
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-react-jsx",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

**Webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

/** @returns {String} an absolute path */
function toRoot(rootRelativeDir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, '..', rootRelativeDir);
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/app.js', './styles/flex.less'].map(toRoot),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: toRoot('.webpack/dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {}
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              /* General options are read using .babelrc - only webpack loader specific here */
              cacheDirectory: toRoot('.webpack/babel_cache')
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin([toRoot('public')])]
};
```

Comment: [Related Github discussion](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My underlying problem was that some Node packages are not written using ES5 syntax, and the Babel transforms did not transform them for some reason. This is a [normal issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3564)

Finding *why* this happened was pretty easy (@Vincent's answer helped); I had `exclude: /node_modules/` in the config. Of course, removing this would "fix" the issue, but it would introduce new issues, as the `exclude` is there for a reason, as you don't want Babel to process *every* file in there.

So what you want is this: **selective filtering allowing *some* modules**.

Trying to construct a regex that will allow a list of packages under node_modules, but restrict the rest is cumbersome and error prone. Thankfully the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions) describe that the condition rules, of which `exclude` is one, can be

- A string: To match the input must start with the provided string. I. e. an absolute directory path, or absolute path to the file.
- A RegExp: It's tested with the input.
- A function: It's called with the input and must return a truthy value to match.
- An array of Conditions: At least one of the Conditions must match.
- An object: All properties must match. Each property has a defined behavior.

Creating such a function is easy! So instead of having `exclude: /node_modules`, I changed it to be `exclude: excludeCondition`, where `excludeCondition` is the following function:

```
function excludeCondition(path){

  const nonEs5SyntaxPackages = [
    'material-ui',
    'tcomb-additional-types'
  ]

  // DO transpile these packages
  if (nonEs5SyntaxPackages.some( pkg => path.match(pkg))) {
    return false;
  }

  // Ignore all other modules that are in node_modules
  if (path.match(toRoot("node_modules"))) { return true; }

  else return false;
}
```

This fixed my issue, as there is just a tiny number of packages using ES2015 syntax, so adding them to the allowlist is manageable.

---

**Addendum**
Since people ask about the `toRoot()`, this is the verbatim code:

```
/** @returns {String} an absolute path */
function toRoot(rootRelativeDir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, '..', rootRelativeDir);
}
```

Adapt to your own needs.

The fuller code:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

/** @returns {String} an absolute path */
function toRoot(rootRelativeDir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, '..', rootRelativeDir);
}

function excludeCondition(path) {
  const nonEs2015Packages = ['tcomb-additional-types', 'material-ui'];

  // DO transpile these packages
  if (nonEs2015Packages.some(pkg => path.match(pkg))) {
    return false;
  }

  // Ignore all other modules that are in node_modules
  return Boolean(path.match(toRoot('node_modules')));
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/app.js', './styles/custom.less', './styles/flex.less', './styles/rc_slider.less'].map(toRoot),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: toRoot('.webpack/dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {}
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: excludeCondition,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              /* General options are read using .babelrc - only webpack loader specific here */
              cacheDirectory: toRoot('.webpack/babel_cache')
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin([toRoot('public')])]
};
```

Comment: Just came across this myself. But what is your `toRoot()` function doing? Doesn't seem to be something built into babel?

Comment: `toRoot()` is my own, custom path translator that just creates paths starting from the package root. I have this config file in a subfolder, so this rids me of lots of `"../../"` joined with `__dirname`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why don't you include the toRoot function in it and you leave people guessing?

Comment: Because it was custom for my use case. Depends on folder structure. Have added it in now.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by renaming `.babelrc.js` to `babel.config.js`.

Apparently, `.babelrc` has smaller scope than `babel.config.js`, if you'd like to read more about that, check out this post:

[When to use babel.config.js and .babelrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288375/when-to-use-babel-config-js-and-babelrc)

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me as well. Some node modules don't provide browser support and target node versions that leverage newer ES syntax.

I came across that handy package that transpiles node modules code:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-engine-plugin

It solved my problem regarding IE11 support, hope it helps

Comment: That seems like a hack that doesn't really address the issue, as all it does is enable babel transforms for node_modules, but reading the page sent me in the right direction. It's of course my config that is wrong (I knew that, but not which line): the culprit is of course `exclude: /node_modules/`. I need to selectively enable the modules I need to transpile, it seems.